# DesignerSerializationVisibility(Hidden), EditorBrowsable(Never) etc not working when use interface

Tags: c#, interface, visual-studio-2015, user-controls, designer

Create interface and user control

```
public interface IMyUserControl
{
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [Bindable(false)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    object MyProp { get; set; } 
}
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, IMyUserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Then build project and drop MyUserControl to Form1 from Toolbox.
See Form1.Designer.cs

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // other code
    this.myUserControl1.MyProp = null;
    // other code
}
```

But code below work fine (designer don't generate this.myUserControl1.MyProp = null)

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, IMyUserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public object MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is entirely by design, the code serializer uses Reflection to look at the attributes on the property, it does not look deeper than that.  The workaround is already obvious to you, so use it.

Comment: Too bad. Can forget to put the attribute. Thanks for your answer.